# How do I `git push` without seeing remote output

Tags: git

Since some update to git a while ago, I believe the ability to see remote build status in realtime was added. Is there a way to silence this?

I'm currently pushing a docker image to a resin project, here's what happens

```
$ git push resin master
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 1.07 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

[Info]     Starting build for gh_amingilani/pwnbox, user gh_amingilani
[Info]     Dashboard link: https://dashboard.resin.io/apps/444007/devices
[Info]     Building on 'local'
[Info]     Pulling old image for caching purposes
[Info]     Fetching base image
[==================================================>] 100%
[Info]     Building Standard Dockerfile project
[Build]    Step 1/5 : FROM resin/raspberrypi3-debian:jessie
[Build]     ---> 8fe2e7355e6f
[Build]    Step 2/5 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
[Build]     ---> Running in be6da38a83c0
[Build]    Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
[Build]    Get:1 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [145 kB]
[Build]    Get:2 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2373 B]
[Build]    Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release [148 kB]
[Build]    Get:4 http://archive.raspbian.org jessie InRelease [14.9 kB]
[Build]    Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]
[Build]    Get:6 http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease [22.9 kB]
[Build]    Get:7 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main armhf Packages [17.8 kB]
...
```

How do I make it so that what I see is

```
$ git push resin master
list of known hosts.
    Counting objects: 8, done.
    Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 1.07 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
    Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git.resin.io:gh_amingilani/pwnbox.git
   692cd00..4b40c02  master -> master
```

Comment: This might be due to a git hook.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git push -q --progress resin master
```

Comment: Didn't work, the remote output runs exactly as before.